# Using a Mathematica index as a DiscreteVariable in NDSolve when solving a coupled set of ordinary differential equations

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

**Context**

Since the explanation below of the problem to be solved is lengthy, let me preamble this by saying that I have code that works to solve the problem, but I don't know whether (1) it's optimized, (2) it uses best Mathematica practices. Specifically, (1) is my implementation of the sum using `UnitStep` functions (explained below) fast---i.e. is there a problem with how many evaluations are done when most of those evaluations end up not being used---and (2) is there a less kluge-y way to do this (not involving the sum over all the functions multiplied by `UnitStep`s that takes advantage of built-in, optimized Mathematica functions.

**Question**

I am solving a set of coupled ordinary differential equations in which the functions $f_i$ are indexed by a quantity $i$. There is a quantity $i^*$ that breaks the functions into two sets such that the $f_i$'s where $i\leq i^*$ satisfy one differential equation and the $f_i$'s where $i>i^*$ satisfy another. The right-hand sides of the equations for $i\leq i^*$ depend on all of the functions indexed by $i\leq i^*$. Finally, and most importantly, $i^*$ is itself a function of the $f_i$'s, so the differential equations are changing on the fly.

**Example**

As an example, let's consider the following prototype. For $i > i^*$, $f_i(t)$ exponentially decays. For $i \leq i^*$, $f_i(t)$ grows "exponentially" with a rate equal to $\sum_{j=1}^{i^*}f_j(t)$. Finally, $i^*(t) = \lfloor 1/f_1(t)\rfloor$, so that as $f_1(t)$ grows, $i^*$ decays. The differential equations are then given by
\begin{align}
\frac{df_i}{dt} &=
\begin{cases}
-f_i & i^* < i \leq N\\
f_i\sum_{j=1}^{i^*}f_j & i\leq i^*
\end{cases}~,
\\
i^* &= \left\lfloor \frac{1}{f_1}\right\rfloor~,
\end{align}
where $N$ is the number of functions to be solved for, and let's take as initial conditions
\begin{align}
f_{1\leq i \leq N}(0) &= \frac{1}{N}~,\\
i^*(0) &= N~.
\end{align}
Since $i^*(0) = N$, all of the functions will initially grow, and $i^*$ will decay until $1/f_1 = N-1$, at which point $f_N$ will exponentially decay from then on, etc.

The issue with implementing this set of equations with `NDSolve` is that the summation $\sum_{j=1}^{i^*}f_j$ cannot work. My initial thought was to use `Sum` with $i^*$ as the maximum index, and treat $i^*$ as a `DiscreteVariable`. This doesn't work. Following the working examples in [this previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69756/implement-functions-that-depend-on-previous-value-in-ndsolve) along with a suggestion from a friend, I replaced the truncated sum with a sum over all the functions, with `UnitStep` functions that turn on and off the $f_i$ depending on how $i$ compares to the current value of $i^*$, and then treat $i^*$ as a `DiscreteVariable`. The problem is that if $i^*$ is relatively small, then that sum over all of the $f_i$ uses a lot of values that end up being multiplied by `UnitStep` functions that evaluates to zero, and hence it seems like there are a lot of unnecessary evaluations. Note that $N$ can be very large, on the order of at least hundreds.

**Attempt**

What follows is a simple example of working code that solves the prototype equation for arbitrary $N$.

```
numFunctions=3;
NDSolve[
 Join[
  Table[f[i]'[t] == Piecewise[{
    {-f[i][t], i > iS[t]}
    , {f[i][t] Sum[f[j][t] UnitStep[iS[t] - j], {j, numFunctions}] ,i <= iS[t]}
   }]
   , {i, numFunctions}]
  , Table[f[i][0] == 1/numFunctions, {i, numFunctions}]
  , {iS[0] == numFunctions}
  , {WhenEvent[Floor[1/f[1][t]] + 1 <= iS[t], iS[t] -> Floor[1/f[1][t]]]}
 ]
 , Join[Table[f[i], {i, numFunctions}], {iS}]
 , {t, 0, 10}
 , DiscreteVariables -> {iS}
]
```

Thanks in advance! Hopefully this is an "answerable question" rather than a "discussion-generating question".

Comment: What is `n` in the `Sum` and in the `WhenEvent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a way without using neither `UnitStep` nor `PieceWise` that improves the performance by 75% wrt your code.  It computes 200 functions in a very reasonable time for your toy example.

The main trick is to use a numeric (black box) function to be able to take `Part[... ]` inside it.

```
n = 200;
af = Array[f, n];
taf[t_] := Through[af[t]]
bb[i_?IntegerQ, lim_, f__] := f[[i]] If[i > lim, -1, Tr@f[[;; lim]]];

eqs = Join[Array[f[#]'[t] == bb[#, iS[t], taf@t] &, n],
           Thread[taf@0 == 1/n], {iS[0] == n},
           {WhenEvent[Floor[1/f[1][t]] + 1 <= iS[t], iS[t] -> Floor[1/f[1][t]]]}];
vars = Join[af, {iS}];

xsol = NDSolve[eqs, vars, {t, 0, 10}, DiscreteVariables -> {iS ∈ Integers}];

Plot[Array[f[#][t] &, n] /. xsol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! I'll play around with this (and check myself), but did you by chance check to see if it's faster than the original code (or perhaps it will allow larger `n`'s, even if it doesn't run faster)?

Comment: @march Yup. It's much faster (it takes out something like 75%)

Comment: That's excellent. I definitely had a feeling that the way I was going about things would significantly slow things down.

Comment: how can I use this for two variable functions in a system of coupled pde?