# When using NDsolve, how to determine the positions of steady states?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, chemistry

I am currently trying to numerically solve a set of ordinary differential equations of chemical kinetics. However, I want to implement perturbations only when system reach steady states. For example increase one of the parameters or increase the concentrations of one chemical species.

For example, I want to solve the systems but want to increase, say x[7] a small step each time when system reach steady state. Then how can I implement the trigger event (maybe with `WhenEvent` function)?

---

Resurrected code, without `Subscript`:

```
des = {x[1]'[t], x[2]'[t], x[3]'[t], x[4]'[t], x[5]'[t], 
       x[6]'[t], x[7]'[t], x[8]'[t], x[9]'[t]} ==
 {-k[1] x[1][t] x[3][t] + k[2] x[5][t] + k[3] x[5][t] -
     k[7] x[1][t] x[7][t] + k[8] x[8][t],
  -k[4] x[2][t] x[4][t] + k[5] x[6][t] + k[6] x[6][t] - 
     k[9] x[2][t] x[7][t] + k[10] x[9][t],
  -k[1] x[1][t] x[3][t] + k[2] x[5][t] + k[6] x[6][t],
  -k[4] x[2][t] x[4][t] + k[3] x[5][t] + k[5] x[6][t],
   k[1] x[1][t] x[3][t] - k[2] x[5][t] - k[3] x[5][t],
   k[4] x[2][t] x[4][t] - k[5] x[6][t] - k[6] x[6][t],
  -k[7] x[1][t] x[7][t] - k[9] x[2][t] x[7][t] + k[8] x[8][t] + k[10] x[9][t],
   k[7] x[1][t] x[7][t] - k[8] x[8][t], 
   k[9] x[2][t] x[7][t] - k[10] x[9][t]};

init = {T[1], T[2], T[3], 0, 0, 0, T[4], 0, 0};
```

Comment: Please include your current `NDSolve[ ]`code

Comment: The `Subscript`s, they hurt my eyes! I recommend using, for instance, `x[1][t]` in place of `Subscript[x,1][t]`, because `Subscript`s act weird in Mathematica. Also, your `init`: is this meant to be a set of initial conditions that you are feeding to `NDSolve`, because you should have `==` in place of `=`. Finally, please include values for your initial conditions `Subscript[T, i]`.

Comment: These two posts may be helpful: [(69756)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69756/implement-functions-that-depend-on-previous-value-in-ndsolve?rq=1) and [(84471)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84471/using-a-mathematica-index-as-a-discretevariable-in-ndsolve-when-solving-a-couple).

Comment: Hi, I restored your code, programmatically changing the subscripts.  You can roll back if you like.  (There's a "roll back" button in the edit history.)  I guess it's obvious that the x's are your variables, but it's not real clear what the k's and T's are.  Are they just real constants?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Update notice: `NDSolve` code below used to work without the `Method` option, but somewhere around V10.4, the option became necessary.  Also see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118327/bug-in-ndsolve-whenevent/118528#118528).]*

Based on the OP's original "set-up":

```
des = {x[1]'[t], x[2]'[t], x[3]'[t], x[4]'[t], x[5]'[t],
    x[6]'[t], x[7]'[t], x[8]'[t], 
    x[9]'[t]} == {-k[1] x[1][t] x[3][t] + k[2] x[5][t] + 
     k[3] x[5][t] - k[7] x[1][t] x[7][t] + k[8](*[t]*) x[8][t],
    -k[4] x[2][t] x[4][t] + k[5] x[6][t] + k[6] x[6][t] - 
     k[9] x[2][t] x[7][t] + k[10] x[9][t],
    -k[1] x[1][t] x[3][t] + k[2](*[t]*) x[5][t] + 
     k[6] x[6][t], -k[4] x[2][t] x[4][t] + k[3] x[5][t] + k[5] x[6][t],
    k[1] x[1][t] x[3][t] - k[2] x[5][t] - k[3] x[5][t],
    k[4] x[2][t] x[4][t] - k[5] x[6][t] - k[6] x[6][t],
    -k[7] x[1][t] x[7][t] - k[9] x[2][t] x[7][t] + k[8] x[8][t] + 
     k[10] x[9][t], k[7] x[1][t] x[7][t] - k[8] x[8][t],
    k[9] x[2][t] x[7][t] - k[10] x[9][t]};

init = {T[1], T[2], T[3], 0, 0, 0, T[4], 0, 0};
```

Use the `Norm` of the derivative (with [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html)) to determine when the system is close to a steady-state (same idea as [belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius), who answered first).

```
vars = Array[x, 9];
dvars = Thread[Derivative[1][vars]];

Block[{k, T, ssthreshold},
  k[n_] := k[n] = (SeedRandom[n]; RandomReal[]);
  T[n_] := T[n] = (SeedRandom[n + 10]; RandomReal[]);
  ssthreshold = 1.*^-4;
  (* Print[des]; *) (* to see the ODE *)
  {sol} = 
   NDSolve[{des, Through[vars[0]] == init, 
     With[{df = Through[dvars[t]]}, 
      WhenEvent[Norm[df] < ssthreshold, x[7][t] -> x[7][t] + 0.1]]}, 
    vars, {t, 0, 200}, MaxSteps -> 100000,
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}  (* needed as of V10.4 or so *)
    ]
  ];

Plot @@ {Through[vars[t]] /. sol, Flatten@{t, x[1]["Domain"] /. sol}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This seems good. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to get the events time ?

Comment: @LifeWorks Sure.  Something like `Reap@NDSolve[{..., WhenEvent[Norm[df] < ssthreshold, Sow[t]; x[7][t] -> x[7][t] + 0.1]...},...]`.  There are a few examples in the `WhenEvent` documentation; just search for `Reap` or `Sow`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I've tried reproducing this solution and run into an error. The domain for the x[1] variable and all others is from {t,0.,0.} as written. Manually changing the the domain to {t, 0.,200.} throws an extrapolation error. Any chance you could take a look at the code?

Comment: @tarhawk [I think it's a bug.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118327/bug-in-ndsolve-whenevent).

Comment: @tarhawk Fixed according to advice from Wolfram support.  See updated answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 great! Thanks, actually following the entire discussion was pretty useful for me.

Answer (score 5):

Because the equations are nonlinear, there is no assurance that equilibrium solutions even exist for a given set of `k` and initial conditions.  However, if they do exist, an alternative, and perhaps more informative, approach is to compute them directly:

```
xs = Solve[Thread[Table[0, {i, Length[des[[1]]]}] == des[[2]] /. x[n_][t] -> x[n]],
     Table[x[i], {i, Length[des[[1]]]}]]
```

Although `Solve` warns

```
Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
```

playing a bit with `Reduce` strongly suggests that `Solve` gives all the equilibrium solutions here:

```
{* {{x[3] -> ((k[2] + k[3]) x[5])/(k[1] x[1]), 
      x[4] -> (k[3] (k[5] + k[6]) x[5])/(k[4] k[6] x[2]), 
      x[6] -> (k[3] x[5])/k[6], x[8] -> (k[7] x[1] x[7])/k[8], 
      x[9] -> (k[9] x[2] x[7])/k[10]},
   {x[1] -> 0, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> 0, x[8] -> 0, x[9] -> (k[9] x[2] x[7])/k[10]},
   {x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> 0, x[8] -> 0, x[9] -> 0},
   {x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> 0, x[8] -> (k[7] x[1] x[7])/k[8], 
      x[9] -> 0}} *}
```

(For each of the four solutions, any `x` that do not appear can take any value.)  With the equilibrium solutions known, one can linearize the equations `des` about them, Laplace transform the resulting linear equations, and `Solve` them to obtain the `Eigensystem`s, completely determining the perturbed solutions in closed form.

**Addendum**

In answer to the question posed below in a comment, the right side of `des` can be linearized about an equilibrium solution without difficulty.  (The left side already is linear.)

```
desl = Coefficient[des[[2]] /. x[n_][t] -> x[n] + e dx[n], e]

(* {dx[5] k[2] + dx[5] k[3] + dx[8] k[8] - dx[3] k[1] x[1] - 
      dx[7] k[7] x[1] - dx[1] k[1] x[3] - dx[1] k[7] x[7], 
    dx[6] k[5] + dx[6] k[6] + dx[9] k[10] - dx[4] k[4] x[2] - 
      dx[7] k[9] x[2] - dx[2] k[4] x[4] - dx[2] k[9] x[7], 
    dx[5] k[2] + dx[6] k[6] - dx[3] k[1] x[1] - dx[1] k[1] x[3], 
    dx[5] k[3] + dx[6] k[5] - dx[4] k[4] x[2] - dx[2] k[4] x[4], 
    -dx[5] k[2] - dx[5] k[3] + dx[3] k[1] x[1] + dx[1] k[1] x[3], 
    -dx[6] k[5] - dx[6] k[6] + dx[4] k[4] x[2] + dx[2] k[4] x[4], 
    dx[8] k[8] + dx[9] k[10] - dx[7] k[7] x[1] - dx[7] k[9] x[2] - dx[1] k[7] x[7] - 
      dx[2] k[9] x[7], 
    -dx[8] k[8] + dx[7] k[7] x[1] + dx[1] k[7] x[7], 
    -dx[9] k[10] + dx[7] k[9] x[2] + dx[2] k[9] x[7]} *)
```

At this point, equilibrium values of `x` are substituted (via `Rule`s) into the last result and the `Eigenvalues`s computed.  These `Eigenvalues`s are the growth rates of the perturbations `dx`.  (Complex `Eigenvalues`s indicate oscillatory solutions.)  For instance, if all equilibrium values are `0`, then

```
Eigenvalues[(CoefficientArrays[desl, Array[dx, 9]][[2]] // Normal) /. 
  Thread[Array[x, 9] -> 0]]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -k[2] - k[3], -k[5] - k[6], -k[8], -k[10]} *)
```

Hence, if any of `k[2] + k[3]`, `k[5] + k[6]`, `k[8]`, or `k[10]` are negative, then perturbations grow exponentially.  More generally, one would substitute one of the four equilibrium solutions `xs` derived earlier into the perturbed equations.

Another advantage of the procedure described here is this: In the event that an equilibrium admits exponentially growing perturbations, then attempts to solve for that equilibrium using `NDSolve` are likely to be unstable too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you mind expand a bit on the `EigenSystem` part?

Comment: @LifeWorks  This is something I should have done originally.  I now have.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

An example perturbing a simple RL circuit when it's about to reach the steady state.

```
R = 1;
L = 1;
V = 1;
SeedRandom[43];
sol = NDSolve[{R i[t] + L i'[t] == V, i[0] == 0,
              WhenEvent[{i'[t] ==  .01}, i[t] -> i[t] + RandomReal[{-.5, .5}]],
              WhenEvent[{i'[t] == -.01}, i[t] -> i[t] + RandomReal[{-.5, .5}]]}, 
              i, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[(i /. sol[[1]])[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]