# Bug in NDSolve/WhenEvent?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, bugs, event-detection

**Bug introduced after 10.0, in 10.3 or earlier and persisting in 13.2.1**

---

I'm fairly sure the following is a bug, and I would normally just report it to WRI.  However, this is related to my answer to
[When using NDsolve, how to determine the positions of steady states?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86276/when-using-ndsolve-how-to-determine-the-positions-of-steady-states)
So I thought I would post it as a question, for two reasons.  One is to let the community verify that it is in fact a bug.  The other is to give a reference to the issue for the other question.

Here is a simplified example.  With the `WhenEvent` rule `x[t] -> 1.`, `NDSolve` fails to integrate the ODE and gives no message.

```
{sol} = NDSolve[
  {x'[t] == -0.08 x[t], x[0] == 1.,
   WhenEvent[Norm[{x'[t]}] < 0.0001, {x[t] -> 1.}]},
  {x}, {t, 0, 200}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One the other hand, using an empty action, the system is integrated:

```
{sol} = NDSolve[
  {x'[t] == -0.08 x[t], x[0] == 1.,
   WhenEvent[Norm[{x'[t]}] < 0.0001, {}]},
  {x}, {t, 0, 200}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Problem also seems connected to the use of the derivative `x'[t]` in the event condition.  It works fine with `x[t]`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug?

*[Mathematica 10.4.1, OSX 10.11.4.]*

Comment: Same behaviour on `10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) `. Any deviation from your first example seems to work, e.g. `WhenEvent[Norm[{x'[t]}] < 0.0001, {Print@t; x[t] -> 1.}]`, which indicates that the default step size and resolution is adequate to locate events. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Works fine in v9.0.1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IpevD.png I think it's safe to say it's a bug.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Change `Print@t` to any other expression also works (e.g. an empty list `{}`). Pretty strange.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a workaround suggested by the response I received from WRI:

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -0.08 x[t], x[0] == 1., 
   WhenEvent[Norm[{x'[t]}] < 0.0001, {x[t] -> 1.}]},
  {x}, {t, 0, 200},
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
  ]

Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 200}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Warning: This option works by converting the system to a DAE, for which only machine-real code is available.  That is probably sufficient for most cases, but it does limit one's options.  For example, you cannot change `WorkingPrecision`, and it will not solve a BVP.

The response from WRI suggested using `NDSolve[.., SolveDelayed -> True]`, which indeed works.  Its use with `NDSolve` is pretty much undocumented, and it shows up in red in the front end.  One can find references to it in the documentation for the messages 
[`NDSolve::ntdv`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NDSolve/ntdv.html)
and
[`NDSolve::ndnum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NDSolve/ndnum.html).
While the text for `NDSolve::ntdv` in the documentation advises trying `SolveDelayed -> True`, the text in my current system (V10.4.1) reads like this:

```
NDSolve::ntdv
(*
"Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. \
Consider using the option \
Method->{\"EquationSimplification\"->\"Residual\"}."
*)
```

It's hard to know which option should be considered the preferred solution.  After a little testing, they seem to produce **identical** solutions, so I feel they might be invoking the same internal code.  I opted for `"EquationSimplification"` because it is documented for DAEs.

Also, the response from WRI did not indicate that they thought this was a bug (or "issue"); it did not indicate otherwise either.

Comment: I only saw this now: `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"` is the same as the old deprecated `SolveDelayed -> True`

Comment: @user21 Thanks.  I thought that was probably the case.

Comment: Its seems that the first action in `WhenEvent` will be ignored. Another workaround may be add a harmless action to feed it; (e.g. `WhenEvent[Norm[{x'[t]}] < 0.0001, {}; x[t] -> 1.]`), which is also pointed out by István Zachar in the comment under the post.

Comment: Wow, you cracked the 100K. Well done!

Comment: @user21 Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -0.08 x[t], x[0] == 1., 
   WhenEvent[Norm[{x'[t]}] < 0.0001, x[t] -> 1.; x[t] -> 1]}, {x}, {t,
    0, 200}]
```

[image]

Comment: But `x'[t]` does seem to be available in this similar code: `NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == 1, WhenEvent[x'[t] < 0, Null; x[t] -> 3 - x[t]]}, x, {t, 0, 20}]`.  Similarly it is used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5591/4999), albeit in the pre-WhenEvent days, to locate all local extrema.  -- During integration, the value of `x'[t]` is one of the `"SolutionDataComponents"` and can be used in the event (but not the action, I think) of a `WhenEvent` call.  See [Components and Data Structures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) for more.

Comment: @MichaelE2
And apparently similarly `{sol} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -0.08 x[t], x[0] == 1., 
   WhenEvent[Norm[{x'[t]}] < 0.0001, x[t] -> 1.; x[t] -> 1]}, {x}, {t,
    0, 200}]` Works fine. Now also allowing plotting of velocity.